# How to pre filter the data Set before loading all the data in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, out-of-memory, powerbi-desktop

I want to pre filter the data set before loading all the data in Power BI. I am loading data from Azure table and when trying to refresh it, its loading all the data into dataset in one go. I am using the Azure table for time series data so, Azure table are increasing day by day. Due to this, Schedule Refresh is throwing the error

> This operation was canceled because there wasn’t enough memory to finish

Comment: You may find incremental refresh useful
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64093061/power-bi-incremental-refresh-from-azure-blob

Answer (score 0):

After a long re-search, I found a way to manage this. Please follow the steps for this.

Step 1: Open the Power BI Report in Power BI Desktop 
Step 2: Click on Transform Data and select
[Transform Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meAuf.png) 
Step 3: In Home Tab, Click on Manage Parameter section and select
[New Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJtaN.png) 
Step 4: Configure the data as per given [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icLWM.png) 
Step 5: Right click on Parameter and select "**Convert to Query**" 
Step 6: Now go to the advance editor of your dataset and apply the filter on DateTime column. [See the screenshot for more information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCKJ5.png)

Thanks 
Ashutosh